# How to create a new string list from a list of strings excluding one variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have a list of strings and I'm trying to iterate through it and create each iteration a new list without one of the strings.
I tried the following:

```
tx_list = ['9540a4ff214d6368cc557803e357f8acebf105faad677eb06ab10d1711d3db46', 'dd92415446692593a4768e3604ab1350c0d81135be42fd9581e2e712f11d82ed',....]
for txid in tx_list:
    tx_list_copy = tx_list
    tx_list_without_txid = tx_list_copy.remove(txid)
```

But each iteration the new list is empty.

Comment: `tx_list_copy = tx_list` That does NOT make a new copy of `tx_list`.  `tx_list_copy` refers to the SAME list object.

Comment: The line: `tx_list_copy = tx_list` does not make a copy. Perhaps you meant: `tx_list_copy = tx_list[:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement:

```
tx_list_copy = tx_list
```

does not copy the list but it refers to the same memory object: `tx_list` and `tx_list_copy` are different references to the **same memory object list**. This means that if you edit the first one, the second one will be edited too.
Instead, in order to copy the original list, you should use the `.copy()` method:

```
for txid in tx_list:
    tx_list_copy = tx_list.copy()     # copy the original list
    tx_list_copy.remove(txid)         # remove the txid element, this is already the list without the txid element
```

Then, to remove the `txid` element from `tx_list_copy`, you could use the `.remove()` method, which removes the element in the `tx_list_copy`, so this is already the list you need.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
for i in range(len(tx_list)) :
    tx_list_without_txid = tx_list[:i] + tx_list[i+1:]
    # do something with the new list...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create multiple lists then this won't work you'll need to create a dictionary:

```
list_box = {}
for txid in tk_list:
    list_box[txid] = tx_list.copy()
    list_box[txid].remove(txid)
```

this will create a new list with name `list_box[txid]` where txid is  the element that dosen't exists in the list(for better understanding).
Hope it will help!